# How to replace word occurrence in ranges specified using sed command?

Tags: sed, text-processing

```
str="I want to abc replace a word abc in a sentence abc of file abc by giving abc specifying a abc multiple abc range to abc the sed abc command abc."
```

The above sting str has word "abc" **10 times** occured,I want to replace "abc" occured from **2nd-4th** time and **6th-8th** with word "xyz" using sed command.

after sed command on string str ,str should look as below:

```
str="I want to abc replace a word xyz in a sentence xyz of file xyz by giving abc specifying a xyz multiple xyz range to xyz the sed abc command abc."
```

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`?

Comment: Yes am  looking specific to sed,if any other simpler and shorter way is there let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's clever or not but here is my GNU sed solution:

```bsh
sed 's/abc/nonABC/5;s/abc/nonABC/8g;s/abc/xyz/2g;s/nonABC/abc/g' <<<"$str"
```

#### Explanation:

```bsh
sed '
    s/abc/nonABC/5;   # replace only 5th occurrence of 'abc' word with another word (i, e: 'nonABC') 
    s/abc/nonABC/8g;  # replace 8th to the next occurrences of 'abc' with another word too
    s/abc/xyz/2g;     # replace all occurrences of 'abc' word start from 2th place
    s/nonABC/abc/g    # get back the all changed 'abc' from 'nonABC'
' <<<"$str"           # from 'str' as input
```

And with `awk` and of course clever:

```bsh
awk '{printf ( 2<=NR && NR<=8 && NR!=5 )?$0"xyz":$0RS}' RS='abc' <<<"$str"
```

#### Explanation:

- `RS='abc'` defines 'abc' as **R**ecord **S**eparator
- if **N**umber of **R**ecord was between 2 and 8 `2<=NR && NR<=8` but not equal with 5 `NR!=5`, then print the current record `$0` and the replace word `xyz`, otherwise, print the record and `abc` itself. you can use `$0"abc"` in place of `$0RS.`

If your ranges are like: [(2-4),(8-10),(12-15),(18-20),(26-29) ...] as [you mentioned in comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580360/how-to-replace-word-occurrence-in-ranges-specified-using-sed-command/581365?noredirect=1#comment804624_581365) then `awk` is best command for this job. Only you need is specifying the ranges as multiple condition:

```
( (2<=NR && NR<=4) || (8<=NR && NR<=10) || (12<=NR && NR<=15) || (18<=NR && NR<=20) || (26<=NR && NR<=29) || (...) )
```

Comment: @Kasiya-Both answers seems good,but if the file/string is large and the ranges are more we still need an efficient solution.
Solution like just specifying ranges to sed/awk command, ranges like: [(2-4),(8-10),(12-15),(18-20),(26-29) .....]

Comment: yes for such cases awk is best.

Answer (score 2):

Another way with the helping of brace expansion, you can do:

```
sed '-es/abc/xyz/'{8..6} '-es/abc/xyz/'{4..2} <<<"$str"
```

Please note that range should be always `max` first in `{max#..min#}` even first max ranges should be specify at first.

You can also specify which positions range should replace in `{x,y,z}` format, where numbers should be `x>y>z`:

```
sed '-es/abc/xyz/'{8,6,4,2} <<<"$str"
```

Note that if you use same number `{x,x}` it will cause a problem and will replace position `x` again and again (BTW for this there is `s/abc/xyz/X` alternative where `X` is position number).

---

I learned this with from [Stéphane Chazelas's answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432997/72456)